# AesManaged versus RijndaelManaged

Tags: .net-3.5, encryption, .net-2.0

I'm currently porting a piece of code written in .NET 3.5 to 2.0.
At some point in the code (heavy load) the AesManaged class is being used, are there any performance gains from this implementation compared to RijndaelManaged, and should there be any risk when changing from AesManaged to RijndaelManaged concerning heavy load?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually there is one very subtle difference: Block size.

Rijndael supports block sizes of 128, 192, 256 bits.
AES supports only 128 bit block sizes.